# Maximal Set of Vertices in Undirected graph interconnected to each other

Tags: java, graph

I am writing a program for which a Graph subproblem has to be addressed. I have to return a maximal set of vertices with all the vertices interconnected to each other.

Let say we have a graph with 5 vertices represented by an adjacency matrix:

0 0 1 1 1

0 0 1 1 1

1 1 0 1 0

1 1 1 0 0

1 1 0 0 0

I should get: 2 3 4 or 1 3 4 as an answer.

I am not sure about the best way to approach this problem.

I have tried solving this using bruteforce which is takes a lot of time when the number of vertices increase.

I also tried using Johnson's algorithm to find all the elementary cycles in the graph using SCC and then checked the vertices of those cycles manually to find set with all interconnected vertices.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What was the problem w/ Johnson's algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean by "interconnected to each other", simply reachable, or having a vertex connecting each pair?

Comment: Well that means vertix connecting each other and it should give me a maximal set. For ex: 1 2 are connected and 1 3 are connected, so the maximal set will be either 1 2 or 1 3. But If 2 3 are also connected along with 1 2 and 1 3 then maximal set will be 1 2 3. Is there a term in Graph theory for such problems?

Comment: With Johnson's algorithm, I can find all the elementary cycles but that is not what I want so further on I need to process all the cycles manually to work with my requirement and that again takes a lot of time. I am just wondering what this problem is called in Graph Theory.

Comment: in your example everything is interconnected - so come back with  a precise definition of what you seek